# How to get ISO format from time in milliseconds in Java?

Tags: java, date

Is it simple way to get `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS` from time in millisecond?  I've found some information how to do this from `new Date()` or `Calendar.getInstance()`, but couldn't find if it can be done from long (e.g. `1344855183166`)

Comment: By "ISO format", do you mean [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I thought you had asked how to get the time in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"

One way is to use java's SimpleDateFormat:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

NOTE that this is not thread-safe.

...

```
Date d = new Date(1344855183166L);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
String dateStr = sdf.format(d);
```

...

Answer (score 5):

If you have epoch millis. The below line should work,

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).toString()
```

Answer (score 4):

As said by Sridhar Sg's the code:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).toString()
```

will work as the `toString()` method will give you the ISO-8601 extended format representation (with separators).

Note that the `Instant` class **will only work from JDK 8** (introduction of the `java.time` package) unless you use [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport to Java 6 and 7.

If millis = 1603101879234 the above method will return: `2020-10-19T10:04:39.234Z`

If you need other kind of format, like the ISO-8601 basic format (without separators except the T in the middle) you can use a custom `DateTimeFormatter` like this:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSX") // millisecond precision
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

String basicIso = outFormatter.format(instant);
```

For the same millis = 1603101879234 the above method will yield: `20201019T100439.234Z`.

Comment: Thanks. In the basic ISO 8601 format you still need a decimal mark (comma or dot) before the milliseconds. Don’t hardcode the `Z` as a literal in the format pattern string. Use format pattern letter ´X` to produce the `Z` for offset zero (“Zulu time”). java.time has been backported to Java 6 and 7 in [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in fact my usage was a bit different and I wanted to remove all separator including the millisecond. I edited my answer to fit better to the ISO basic format. Thanks also to point out the X is better than hardcoding the 'Z'.

Comment: This is another way to get UTC 
`Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`

Answer (score 3):

The `Date` constructor does take a long (milliseconds) doesn't it?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The question does not mention time zone, so I'll assume you meant [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT. The question does not explain "ISO format", so I'll assume you meant [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This happens to be the default for third-party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library. This *is* thread-safe.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

System.out.println( "That moment: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime( 1344855183166L, org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
That moment: 2012-08-13T10:53:03.166Z
```

---

If the original poster meant a Poland time zone…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

// Time Zone list… http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone warsawTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Warsaw" );
System.out.println( "That moment in Poland: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime( 1344855183166L, warsawTimeZone ) );
```

When run…

```
That moment in Poland: 2012-08-13T12:53:03.166+02:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`new Date(millis);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor of [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

```
new Date(1344855183166L);
```