# Can't get Australian date/time

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to generate the correct Australian date/time.  But it continues to return GMT time.

Any ideas would be great

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+10:00")).getTime()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney");
calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);

Date currentTime = calendar.getTime();
```

Check out [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html) for a list of all time zones with a few more examples.

Comment: Hi Casey - unfortunately it didn't work.  Still getting GMT time.  I am using an android emulator - do you think it has anything to do with that?

Comment: I answered my own question - the emulator time was set to GMT time!!

Comment: It is wrong answer. When converting the Calendar object to a Date object the timezone is lost. Date takes device timezone.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Australia has a few different time zones with different offsets. See [this list](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

You should specify a time zone by name rather than offset so that your date-time library may assist with [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or other anomalies.

(b) caseyscarborough gave [a correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256270/642706). Here is the same kind of code but in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone adelaideTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Australia/Adelaide" );
org.joda.time.DateTime adelaideDateTime =  new org.joda.time.DateTime( adelaideTimeZone ); // Standard time is +09:30 of UTC.
System.out.println( "Now in Adelaide: " + adelaideDateTime );
System.out.println( "Same moment in UTC: " + adelaideDateTime.toDateTime( org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
Now in Adelaide: 2013-11-28T14:21:21.192+10:30
Same moment in UTC: 2013-11-28T03:51:21.192Z
```